# %%f in a batch file with Windows 7 Professional 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I have a line like the following in a several batch files:

```
FOR %%f IN (%*) DO something.exe %%f
```

I've used them for a long time with no problem. I recently had to replace my hard drive and had Windows 7 reinstalled just as it was before as far as I know. Now when I run any of the batch files with this kind of line in it, they aren't pre-processing the "%*". So for something like "XXX.bat *.txt" I get:

Unable to open input file "*.txt"

I'm running Windows 7 as a virtual machine in Parallels, upgraded from version 8 to 10, if that makes a difference. They also upgraded my Mac OS from Mountain Lion to Yosemite.

Even more strange, this little batch file works fine:

```
@ECHO off
FOR %%f IN (%*) DO start gvim %%f
```

But this one gives the message it can't find t? (where t? should parse out to t1, t2, and t3):

```
@ECHO off
FOR %%f IN (%*) DO af2.exe %%f
```

And I tried adding the "start" to it, same results.

Maybe a simpler way of saying it is:

This works:

af2 2014A 2014B 2014C

But this:

af2 2014?

gives an error about trying to access a file called "2014?"

And af2 calls, for each file, a program I wrote and have used for 20+ years that just gives a few statistics on a file.

Comment: I've noticed also that %date% is now just a 2-digit year where it was 4 digits on my previous install. For example, it now shows "Thu 05/07/15" where before it would been "Thu 05/07/2015". Obviously, that's not directly related to the issue at hand, but I thought it might give someone a clue.

Comment: %date% will simply use whatever short date format you've set under Region and Language in the Control Panel. Regarding your problem, from the same location if you try `type filename.txt` does it work? Wondering if it's some sort of permissions issue or something.

Comment: If I do each file manually one at a time, it works fine. The batch file's just not parsing the * wildcard.

Comment: Try fixing .BAT-related registry entries via the [File Association Fixer](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/file-association-fixer-2-windows-10-8-7), reboot and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Command Extensions are disabled for some reason. The command extensions involve serious changes to [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) as per `CALL /?`.

However, next excerpt from `CMD /?` shows some solution hints:

> Command Extensions are enabled by default.  You may also disable
>   extensions for a particular invocation by using the `/E:OFF` switch. 
>   You can enable or disable extensions for all invocations of `CMD.EXE`
>   on a machine and/or user logon session by setting either or both of
>   the following `REG_DWORD` values in the registry using `REGEDIT.EXE`:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\EnableExtensions
> ```
>
> and/or
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\EnableExtensions
> ```
>
> to either `0x1` or `0x0`.  The user specific setting takes precedence
>   over the machine setting.  The command line switches take precedence
>   over the registry settings.
>
> In a batch file, the `SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS` or
>   `DISABLEEXTENSIONS` arguments takes precedence over the `/E:ON` or
>   `/E:OFF` switch. See `SETLOCAL /?` for details.

**Example**

```
==>type D:\bat\cliParser.bat
@echo OFF >NUL
echo   all %%* = %*
set /A "ii=0"
:loopfor
  echo param %%%ii% = %0
  SHIFT
  set /A "ii+=1"
  if not [%0]==[] goto :loopfor
goto :eof

==>D:\bat\cliParser.bat aaa bbb
  all %* = aaa bbb
param %0 = D:\bat\cliParser.bat
param %1 = aaa
param %2 = bbb

==>cmd /E:OFF /C D:\bat\cliParser.bat aaa bbb
  all %* = *
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
param %3 = D:\bat\cliParser.bat
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
param %3 = aaa
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
param %3 = bbb
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The system cannot find the batch label specified - eof

==>
```

Comment: It's very odd. All indications are that it's enabled for both local machine and current user. I added the setlocal enableextensions to a batch file with an error check to give me a message if it was unable to enable them. No error message and the batch file still does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I have a folder on my desktop with a bunch of .exe files in them from programs I've written. It also has a folder with some .bat files in it. In many cases, the .bat file calls one of the .exe files that has the same root name (af2.bat calls af2.exe). That works fine **IF** the folder with the .bat files in it precedes the other folder in the PATH variable, which it did on my previous install (and does now on this one).

Just gotta love those subtle little problems.

Thanks for all the input. :)